# Efficient creation of a matrix of offsets

Tags: r

#### Goal

I want to use a long vector of numbers, to create a matrix where each column is a successive offset (lag or lead) of the original vector. If `n` is the maximum offset, the matrix will have dimensions `[length(vector), n * 2 + 1]` (because we want offsets in both directions, and include the 0 offset, i.e. the original vector).

#### Example

To illustrate, consider the following vector:

```
test <- c(2, 8, 1, 10, 7, 5, 9, 3, 4, 6)

[1]  2  8  1 10  7  5  9  3  4  6
```

#### Expected output

Now we create offsets of values, let's say for `n == 3`:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA    2    8    1   10
 [2,]   NA   NA    2    8    1   10    7
 [3,]   NA    2    8    1   10    7    5
 [4,]    2    8    1   10    7    5    9
 [5,]    8    1   10    7    5    9    3
 [6,]    1   10    7    5    9    3    4
 [7,]   10    7    5    9    3    4    6
 [8,]    7    5    9    3    4    6   NA
 [9,]    5    9    3    4    6   NA   NA
[10,]    9    3    4    6   NA   NA   NA
```

I am looking for an efficient solution. `data.table` or `tidyverse` solutions more than welcome.

Returning only the rows that have no `NA`'s (i.e. rows 4 to 7) is also ok.

#### Current solution

```
lags  <- lapply(3:1, function(x) dplyr::lag(test, x))
leads <- lapply(1:3, function(x) dplyr::lead(test, x))
l <- c(lags, test, leads)
matrix(unlist(l), nrow = length(test))
```

Comment: Also `library(data.table) ; data.table(test)[, c(shift(test, 3:1), shift(test, 0:3, type = "lead"))]` or if you want a matrix without an intermediate step, maybe `do.call(cbind, (c(shift(test, 3:1), shift(test, 0:3, type = "lead"))))`. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055927/how-can-i-automatically-create-n-lags-in-a-timeseries/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485384/reshape-of-time-series-in-r/). Also, I doubt the efficiency `embed` as it is a for loop internally. I would do some benchmarks if efficiency really matters.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, there only seems to be a `for` loop when passing a matrix. For the case of the vector I think it is a single indexing call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R, you can use `embed` to get rows 4 through 7. You have to reverse the column order, however.

```
embed(test, 7)[, 7:1]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    2    8    1   10    7    5    9
[2,]    8    1   10    7    5    9    3
[3,]    1   10    7    5    9    3    4
[4,]   10    7    5    9    3    4    6
```

**data**

```
test <- c(2, 8, 1, 10, 7, 5, 9, 3, 4, 6)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will produce what you need...

```
n <- 3
t(embed(c(rep(NA,n), test, rep(NA,n)), length(test)))[length(test):1,]

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA    2    8    1   10
 [2,]   NA   NA    2    8    1   10    7
 [3,]   NA    2    8    1   10    7    5
 [4,]    2    8    1   10    7    5    9
 [5,]    8    1   10    7    5    9    3
 [6,]    1   10    7    5    9    3    4
 [7,]   10    7    5    9    3    4    6
 [8,]    7    5    9    3    4    6   NA
 [9,]    5    9    3    4    6   NA   NA
[10,]    9    3    4    6   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by constructing the matrix from a long vector and returning only the wanted columns and rows:

```
test <- c(2, 8, 1, 10, 7, 5, 9, 3, 4, 6)
n_offs <- 3L
n_row <- length(test) + n_offs + 1L
matrix(rep(c(rep(NA, n_offs), test), n_row), nrow = n_row)[1:length(test), 1:(n_offs * 2L + 1L)]
```

> ```
>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
>  [1,]   NA   NA   NA    2    8    1   10
>  [2,]   NA   NA    2    8    1   10    7
>  [3,]   NA    2    8    1   10    7    5
>  [4,]    2    8    1   10    7    5    9
>  [5,]    8    1   10    7    5    9    3
>  [6,]    1   10    7    5    9    3    4
>  [7,]   10    7    5    9    3    4    6
>  [8,]    7    5    9    3    4    6   NA
>  [9,]    5    9    3    4    6   NA   NA
> [10,]    9    3    4    6   NA   NA   NA
> ```

A variant which just returns the same result as `embed(test, 7)[, 7:1]` is:

```
matrix(rep(test, length(test) + 1L), nrow = length(test) + 1L)[
  seq_len(length(test) - 2L * n_offs), seq_len(n_offs * 2L + 1L)]
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
> [1,]    2    8    1   10    7    5    9
> [2,]    8    1   10    7    5    9    3
> [3,]    1   10    7    5    9    3    4
> [4,]   10    7    5    9    3    4    6
> ```